# MATLAB - do the equivalent of R `a[-b]` in MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

What is the equivalent of `a[-b]` in MATLAB? `b` is a list of indices. I tried Googling it and still don't know.

Comment: What is `a[~b]` in R?

Comment: @Pascal do you know R?

Comment: Hum, well, a little bit, I confess.

Comment: @Pascal idk how do you select everything in an array in R *except* for some indexes?

Comment: @Pascal oh. How do you do that in MATLAB?

Comment: Well, what you asked is the Matlab syntax.

Comment: @Pascal this conversation was quite funny.

Comment: What is `b`? Is it a logical array the same size as `a`, or is it a list of indices?

Comment: @beaker list of indices

Comment: OK. Time to provide a reproducible example. Voted to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I think you're looking for `a(b) = []`, but I agree, an example would be extremely helpful.